# How to pass switch parameter from one powershell script to another?

Tags: powershell, parameters, switch-parameter

I have two PowerShell scripts and use them on Linux with PowerShell Core, and want to pass the switch parameter from `one.ps1` to `second.ps1`, but the `$args` is populated as a string with `True` and `False` sub-strings in it, which is not accepted by the `second.ps1`, as it has validation in param block.

How do I change to make it work? I know I can manually enumerate all the parameters of `second.ps1` and make up a command argument string, but considering there are so many parameters in `second.ps1`, is there a better way ?

My scripts look like this:

```
# one.ps1
param(
    [string][ValidateSet("value1", "value2")]$para1,
    [switch]$para3 = $false
)

Write-Host "one.ps1: para1=$para1"
Write-Host "one.ps1: para3=$para3"

Write-Host "args=$args"

pwsh ./second.ps1 $args
```

second.ps1

```
# second.ps1
param(
    [string][ValidateSet("value1", "value2")]$para1="value1",
    [string][ValidateSet("value3", "value4")]$para2="value3",
    [switch]$para3 = $false,
    [switch]$para4 = $false,
    [switch]$para5 = $false,
    [switch]$para6 = $false,
    [switch]$para7 = $false,
    [switch]$para8 = $false
)

Write-Host "second.ps1: para1=$para1"
Write-Host "second.ps1: para2=$para2"
Write-Host "second.ps1: para3=$para3"
Write-Host "second.ps1: para4=$para4"
Write-Host "second.ps1: para5=$para5"
Write-Host "second.ps1: para6=$para6"
Write-Host "second.ps1: para7=$para7"
Write-Host "second.ps1: para8=$para8"
```

Here is the command to use them

```
pwsh one.ps1 -para1 value1 -para2 value3 -para3:true -para4:false
```

Error message:

```
one.ps1: para1=value1
one.ps1: para3=True
args=-para2 value3 -para4 False
second.ps1: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'para1'. The argument "False" does not belong to the set "value1,value2" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.
```

Comment: [1] take a look at `$PSBoundParameters`. ///// [2] switches default to `$False`, so there is no need to set them in your parameter block. also, there is no need to use `-SwitchParam:$True` ... since merely calling `-SwitchParam` sets it to `$True`.

Comment: @iRon well, no really, if I use `.IsPresent`, how can I tell whether the arg in `$args` is a `switch` and apply IsPresent?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  [1] `$PSBoundParameters` only stores the parameters defined in param block, other parameters that are passed through command line are omitted, here is the content of   `[para1, value1] [para3, True]` in `one.ps1` and since we never reach to `second.ps1`, can't tell the content of it.  [2] removing `=$false` doesn't help on resolving the original issue...

Comment: the Question is about passing a switch parameter ... that seems to require the item to be defined in the parameter block. [*grin*]

Comment: `pwsh ./second.ps1 $args` --> `pwsh ./second.ps1 -para1:$para1 -para3:$para3` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a switch parameter to another PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009106/how-to-pass-a-switch-parameter-to-another-powershell-script)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I think passing `$args` as named parameter for the second script won't be that easy. `$args` is an array of the arguments. Each argument separated by a whitespace. When you pass `$args` to the second script it will be counted as one argument at position one. `$para1` of the second script will take the whole array as its positional parameter.

```
function one 
{# one.ps1
    param(
        [string][ValidateSet("value1", "value2")]$para1,
        [switch]$para3 = $false
    )

    Write-Host "one.ps1: para1=$para1"
    Write-Host "one.ps1: para3=$para3"

    Write-Host "args=$args"
    Write-Host "argsType=$($args.GetType().BaseType)"

    $args
}

$arg = one -para1 value1 -para2 value3 -para3:$true -para4:$false
```

Result:

```
one.ps1: para1=value1
one.ps1: para3=True
args=-para2 value3 -para4: False
argsType=array

PS D:\test> $arg
-para2
value3
-para4:
False
```

As you can see `-para2 value3` isn't a single string but two strings as part of an array. You could write code to rebuild the named prameter string but I think that will be way more work than just to enumerate them. Another soluten would be to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1). However you wold have to provide a hashtable instead of just a string for the first script. Here is a way to  [call another function with args via splatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67601114/10223991).

Answer (score 0):

[Splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1) the `$PSBoundParameters` to pass the arguments bound to declared parameters in `one.ps1`, splat `$args` to pass the remaining arguments:

```
# one.ps1
param(
    [string][ValidateSet("value1", "value2")]$para1,
    [switch]$para3 = $false
)

Write-Host "one.ps1: para1=$para1"
Write-Host "one.ps1: para3=$para3"

Write-Host "args=$args"

pwsh ./second.ps1 @PSBoundParameters @args
```

Comment: Thanks, the splatting pushes a step further, but it has another issue, all the switch names are accepted by `second.ps1` but the values of them are ignore, thus no matter the value is `True` or `False`, since switch name is present, it will be treated as `True`, Note the `para4=True` in the output: ```second.ps1: para1=value1
second.ps1: para2=value3
second.ps1: para3=True
second.ps1: para4=True
second.ps1: para5=False
second.ps1: para6=False
second.ps1: para7=False
second.ps1: para8=False```